# jQuery find .Selector but not nested selector (.selector .selector)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to find all elements which match a selector but not if it is already contained in a matching element.

`$('#container').find('.child').not('.child .child');`

note that the .child elements are not necessary direct descendants.

why doesn't this work ?

I would like to select all element which would appear in `$('#container').find('.child')` but exclude/`filter()` any which would be in here `$('#container').find('.child .child')` because one of its ancestors is a `.child`

```
var children = $('#container').find('.child').filter(function (i, el) {
    return !$(el).closest('.child').length;
});
```

for some reason this doesn't work either [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9yL3to33/1/)

snippet adapted from @RonenCypis answer

```js
var selector = ' .child ';
var children = $('#container').find(selector).filter(function(i, el) {
  return !$(el).closest(selector).length;
});
children.css('background-color', 'blue');
```

```css
#container div {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="child">one
    <div class="child">one one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">two
    <div class="child">two one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">three</div>
  <div class="child">four
    <div class="child">four one</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) instead of `closest` to find ancestors of the current element. `closest` matches the current element in addition to ancestors.

```js
var selector = ' .child ';
var children = $('#container').find(selector).filter(function(i, el) {
  return !$(el).parents(selector).length;
});
children.css('background-color', 'blue');
```

```css
#container div {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="child">one
    <div class="child">one one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">two
    <div class="child">two one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">three</div>
  <div class="child">four
    <div class="child">four one</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:has()` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) in conjunction with `:not()` selector

```
$('div').find('[role="tabpanel"]:not(:has([role="tabpanel"]))');
```

Comment: sorry cant get this to work do you have a working example ?

Answer (score -1):

Demo in the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/9yL3to33/)

You can use `filter()` for that:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var selector = '.child';
var children = $('#container').find(selector).filter(function(i, el){
    return $(el).find(selector).length == 0;
});

children.css('background-color', 'blue');
```

This code will change the background color only for `.child` elements that doesn't have additional `.child` elements inside them.

Comment: Thanks great example but that wasn't what i asked for, using your example only the top level .child should change colour because the others  are within a .child element

Comment: @TarranJones, so i probably didn't understand what exactly you want to achieve. Can you clarify?

Comment: "Demo in the JsFiddle" — Why use a third party site when [we've had this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for over a year?

Comment: @Quentin Because (a) almost nobody knows the feature exists (b) people are more comfortable using familiar sites that have more features than Snippets.